# Returning an array in C of unknown size and using terminating value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am a C novice and am having issues handling arrays of unknown size.

The main issue is my function `my_func`, say, does some work and needs to output a series of values, of unknown size. i.e. if it were a Java function it would return an ArrayList, probably.

From googling, it seems my best bet is to do something like this:

```
MyStruct * myStructArr = (MyStruct *)malloc(MAX*sizeof(MyStruct));
my_func(myStructArr);
```

where the function will fill up the items of the array with appropriate `MyStruct` values. `MAX` is chosen such that it is guaranteed to be bigger than the biggest possible array output of `my_func`.

I'm a little uneasy about this, but I guess this is how things work in C. The only remaining issue is, after calling the function, how do I know how many `myStructArr` values have been set?

It seems the solution is to do something like this:

```
`void my_func(MyStruct * myStructArr){
      //fill up the array (partially)

     // finally
     *myStructArr++ = SomeTerminatingItem;
}
```

Here `SomeTerminatingItem` indicates the last item of the array (further items are not initialized).

So outside `my_func`, after calling it I can do:

```
while(*myStructArr != SomeTerminatingItem){
    // do whatever I want with the item.
    myStructArr++;
}
```

Is this a correct way to do this?

Comment: If you have a compile time defined constant and it's not very big, don't use `malloc()` for this. It appears that you don't even know about `free()`.

Comment: 1) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 2) You cannot return an array in C. 3) A pointer is not an array. 4) Learn [ask] and provide a MCVE.

Comment: If you could let us in on how many elements your array will typically have, and how well you are able to estimate it, we can take this into account in our answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Linked Lists, because it looks like you're returning a pointer to the first item anyway. Also, the C equivalent of a Java ArrayList is a linked list. Basically, make a simple node struct:

```
struct node {
    MyStruct value;
    struct node *next;
};
```

*next should point to the 'next' item in the list. Always make sure you don't lose the pointer to the first item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Returning memory allocated from a function is a delicate issue that should be avoided. You'll always want to structure your code such that memory is allocated and freed on the same level:

```
void* mem = malloc(N);
do_something(mem, N);
free(mem);
```

If you absolutely don't know `N` in advance, because you are reading a file for example, you have to use side effects to effectively return two values.

```
size_t my_func(void **mem) {
    size_t N = figure_out_N();
    *mem = malloc(N);
    return N;
}
```

Use as:

```
void *mem;
size_t N = my_func(&mem);
do_something(mem, N);
free(mem);
```

Using a termination value is a bad idea, since you have to exclude that it can arise by chance anywhere else in your data. It is also inefficient to figure out the size of the array later on if you need to.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. I don't know N until the algorithm is finished. "memory is allocated and freed on the same level"  this is what I was thinking, which is why I thought allocating a "too big" array would be best.

Comment: In that case, yes, you'll have to make an initial guess about the size of the array and figure out a growing strategy, such as reallocating with double the previous size every time it's full. Note that this implies copying the whole array every time. Implementing this is a lot of bookkeeping. If you can use C++, `std::vector` does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a struct MyStruct.

I would recommend creating another struct MyStructArray, which contains a count of elements, and a MyStruct*. That solves forever the problem of keeping the size of the array stored away somewhere, because all you need is contained in MyStructArray.

Answer (score 1):

Linked lists are NOT the equivalent of array lists, they are sequential access and to traverse require following a chain of pointers.  Oddly I read an SO post today which included a link to a C implementation of Java Arraylists - http://m-hewedy.blogspot.co.il/2010/09/java-like-arraylist-in-c.html

For a start implementation using a fixed size array is fine, you can actually even grow/shrink it simply using function [realloc(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)
There's plenty of time to develop more dynamic structures when they're really needed.  For instance using tables of pointers to the structs, allocated & free list to speed insertion, deleting & sorting.

It's likely better to define the function to fill an array up to max elements :

```
 unsigned my_fill_func(MyStruct myStructArr[], unsigned max) {
     unsigned count = 0;

     //fill up the array (partially)
     for ( ; count<max && fill_entry( &myStructArr[ count]);
         count++);

     // finally
     return count;
}
```